# exercise about doubling

Tags: riemannian-geometry, metric-geometry

In Euclidean space, any $R$-ball can be covered by $C$ $\frac{R}{2}$-balls where $C$ is independent of $R$.

But in hyperbolic space, this does not hold.

Here we have a definition :

Def : A metric space is doubling if there is constant $C$ s.t. any ball $B$ can covered by at most $C$ balls whose radius is half the radius of $B$.

Problem : A metric space is doubling iff any $R$-ball is covered by at most $C$ subsets whose diameter is equal to $R$ or smaller than $R$.

Proof : We have a claim that if $E$ has a diameter $R$, then it can be covered by $C'$ $\frac{R}{2}$-balls. How can we prove this ?

Comment: Where did you find this problem? It is incorrect as stated.

Comment: In the book metric structures for Riemannian and non-Riemannian spaces - Gromov, I find the exercise B.2.4. lemma in page 405.

Comment: Thank you. I checked that statement in the above is wrong (I did not read correctly).